# XSD: Child's name is the name of parent's attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Is it possible to validate the following XML, where the parent's child name is it's attribute "name":

```
<root>
  <parent name="foo">
    <foo/>
  </parent>
  <parent name="bar">
    <bar/>
  </parent>
  <parent name="abc">
    <xyz/> <!-- invalid -->
  </parent>
</root>
```

The XSD, as per request:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:complexType name="parentType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <!-- TODO: enforce element name same as it's parent's attribute "name" -->
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="parent" type="parentType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

The "TODO" is where I'm stumped. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Of course it is possible to validate any XML, it might just turn out to be invalid. Please add the *.xsd schema to your post to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **XSD 1.0**, you cannot specify such a constraint directly, but you could specify it using Schematron or check it at the application level.

In **XSD 1.1**, you could use `xsd:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:complexType name="parentType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    <xsd:assert test="@name = local-name(*[1])"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="parent" type="parentType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: thanks for your insight. Would you know if this is possible with DTD or RELAX NG?

Comment: Not sure how offhand.  Ask as separate questions if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an exercise in seeing what can go wrong when you violate the rule "Don't Repeat Yourself" in XML?

Comment: @McQueer unfortunately i have no control over the XML structure. It's coming from a third party. However, i'm unaware of this "rule". Can you please share a reference to it?

Comment: @Jims: [**DRY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is a design principle beyond XML.